Language only changes after re-login
I'm using Angular with the ABP localization module(ASP.NET Boilerplate) to handle multi-language support in my application. Currently, when a user changes the language using the language switcher, the new language setting is only applied after the user logs out and logs back in.
Expected Behavior: The language should change immediately across the application when a new language is selected, without requiring the user to log out and log back in.
Question: How can I configure my Angular ABP application to apply the language change immediately without needing to re-login? Are there any best practices or configurations I might be missing?

Hey there, thank you for asking your question. Please share relevant parts of how your application is implemented, otherwise there is not much advice to be given. Please also try adding what have you tried and worked/ didn't work for you. Looking forward for your reply. Have a wonderful evening!

@DragosAndrei can you be more concrete in the info I need to provide. I'm using ABP localization module.

Is it getting localized server-side or clientside? I'd assume server-side, if it's being cached, but in that case I'd expect you to be appending /en or /ru or something to your URLS to embrace the caching. Are the URLS for different languages all the same, or does each page have its own url for that language?

Can you share with us the code of the language switcher? Maybe it's setting the variable incorrectly, in a way that's only checked during the ngOnInit of the login page or something..... For example, maybe it's only fetching JSON from the language service during initial login, instead of fetching new JSON every time you switch languages.

....So I'd guess we also need the bit where you get a AJAX request to get your languages. Go through the whole thing and make sure that the language ajax stuff triggers not only during initial page load, but also every time the language switcher activates. (Maybe console.log that stuff.)

@DavidSimões can you share how you've setup the ABP localization module with DI?

Don’t know about angular, but on macOS / iOS the app would have to observe the system setting for the language, manually refresh every ui on the screen or in memory, and manually refresh all locations where the system location or items based on it are cached. That’s quite a bit of work and needs to be done right. For example, you might have a button with German text, but scrolled offscreen. You change the language to French. There is a good chance that if you scroll the screen, it will be scrolled in with German text.
There are other settings where changes take effect only after restarting the device, if in Apples opinion apps won’t bother or manage to adapt to changes while running.
